# Unable to access SQL table from appl running as service

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, http.sys, intraweb-10

I have a small test application, made with Delphi 10.3.1 as an Stand Alone `HTTPSYS Intraweb` service. It has an `ADOConnection` and a `ADOTable` and in `FormShow` of unit1, I open the connection, and the table and reads the first 10 rows and add them to a listbox. Just to see that it works and is possible.

When running the application as a Stand Alone `HTTPSYS`, vith visual GUI, it's working nicely, but when I compile it as a service, and install it, on the sql server, or on the development machine, it fails with access Violation, trying to open the table. I suppose it is an Authentication problem.

I have tried to open connection with both `Windows Auth`, and with a specific SQL login, and I have tried running the service with both local system (default) and with the specific SQL account.

What am I missing ?

The Specific SQL login, works in SSMS. I'm able to use it to login and access my tables.

Also, if I create the application as a `DLL` and put it on my `IIS10`, it works fine.

Comment: An access violation is not caused by an authentication problem. It's typically caused by accessing a component that has not yet been created or after it is destroyed. It's impossible to tell you what might be causing this, because we can't see your code from here.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It has nothing to do with authentication.

For the IntraWeb HttpSys Stand Alone program to run as a service, the ServerController.ComInitialization property must be set to ciMultiThreaded.

Thanks for your comment which lead me to look elsewhere. You do deserve the credit.

Regards
Soren